# Problema al sacar información de un JSON

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Java para Android que recoja datos de algunas gasolineras, para ello estoy intentando parsear la info de un JSON, pero no sé cómo acceder a un array dentro de otro array. El archivo en cuestión es así:

```
{
  fields: [
    {
    name: "objectid",
    alias: "objectid",
    type: "esriFieldTypeOID"
    },
    {
    name: "provincia",
    alias: "provincia",
    type: "esriFieldTypeString",
    length: 2048
  }
    ],
  features: [
          {
          attributes: {
            objectid: 5917311,
            provincia: "MÁLAGA",
            municipio: "ESTEPONA",
            localidad: "ESTEPONA",
            código_postal: "29680"
          }, 
          {
          attributes: {
           objectid: 5917312,
           provincia: "MÁLAGA",
           municipio: "ESTEPONA",
           localidad: "ESTEPONA",
           código_postal: "29680"
          }
        ]
        }
```

Hasta ahora tengo solo esto:

```
String url = "https://www.mapabase.es/arcgis/rest/services/Otros/Gasolineras/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json";

    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("fields");

                    for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
                        JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name  = employee.getString("name");
                        String alias = employee.getString("alias");
                        String type = employee.getString("type");

                        text.append(name + ", " +alias+", "+type +"\n \n");


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
```

Pero el código que tengo solo me saca la información de "name", alias y type que está dentro de "fields".

No sé cómo hacer para entrar en "features", luego en "attributes" y sacar la informacion de "provincia", "municipio", etc...

Muchas gracias.

Por favor, si la pregunta puede ser reformulada, decidmelo e intento mejorarla.

Comment: ¿Te han dado el código y no lo entiendes? Sería haciendo exactamente lo mismo que sea ha hecho con `fields`: obtener el array `features` y recorrerlo, sacando los campos de cada elemento.

Comment: @PabloLozano creo que sí que entiendo el código, pero sigo sin saber cómo se haría entrar en features y luego en attributes

Comment: Me parece que te falta una coma antes de features.

Comment: @Juan Sí, muchas gracias, aunque eso no resuelve mi problema jajajaja

Comment: Para tu problema como dijo @PabloLozano tenes que recorrer el array como hiciste para fields.

Comment: JSON es muy fácil de entender. Todo lo que empiece por esto `[`, significa que es un array, todo lo que empiece por esto `{` significa que es un objeto JSON. Partiendo de ahí, si analizas `features` comprenderás que se trata de un array de objetos JSON a los que se accede por medio de la clave `attributes`...

Comment: Puedes por tanto crear una referencia así: **`JSONArray mFeatures = response.getJSONArray("features");`** y luego buscar dentro los objetos JSON que están en cada clave `attributes`, algo así: **`for(int i=0;i< mFeatures.length();i++){ JSONObject attr = mFeatures.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("attributes");  int objectid=attr.getInt("objectid"); String provincia=attr.getString("provincia"); //etc... }`**

Comment: @a.Cedano Muchísimas gracias, lo intentaré en cuanto pueda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON es muy fácil de entender.

- Todo lo que empiece por esto `[`, significa que es un `JSONArray`
- Todo lo que empiece por esto `{` significa que es un objeto `JSONObject`.
- Todo lo que está antes de uno o de otro es la *clave*  de ese objeto.
- Dentro de los objetos hay valores asociados mediante la notación `"clave" : "valor"`

Sabiendo eso, puedes leer cualquier JSON, hasta uno que sea creado por la NASA :)

Partiendo de ahí, según la estructura del JSON tendrás que crear lo que haga falta, sea un `JSONArray`, sean un `JSONObject`, sabiendo que hay casos en los que un `JSONArray` contiene dentro varios `JSONObject` o casos en los que un `JSONObject` contiene dentro uno o varios `JSONArray`.

Vamos a practicar lo aprendido: analizaremos `features`, que es lo que nos interesa aquí:

```
  features: [
          {
          attributes: {
            objectid: 5917311,
            provincia: "MÁLAGA",
            municipio: "ESTEPONA",
            localidad: "ESTEPONA",
            código_postal: "29680"
          }, 
          {
          attributes: {
           objectid: 5917312,
           provincia: "MÁLAGA",
           municipio: "ESTEPONA",
           localidad: "ESTEPONA",
           código_postal: "29680"
          }
        ]
```

- Es un `JSONArray`, porque empieza por `[`
- Tiene dentro dos `JSONObject`
- La clave de esos `JSONObject` es `attributes`
- Y esos `JSONObject` tiene dentro valores mediante la notación `"clave":"valor"`

Comprendido el JSON, entonces puedes escribir el código que lo leerá:

```
/*Referencia a la clave features que es un JSONArray*/
JSONArray mFeatures = response.getJSONArray("features"); 
/*Como es un array, lo recorremos con un bucle, mFeatures.length() indica el tamaño*/
for(int i=0;i< mFeatures.length();i++){ 
    /*Buscamos cada objeto JSON que tiene la clave attributes*/ 
    JSONObject attr = mFeatures.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("attributes"); 
    /*Sacamos el dato que querramos, usando el método adecuado: getInt, getString, etc*/
    int objectid=attr.getInt("objectid"); 
    String provincia=attr.getString("provincia"); 
    //etc... 
}
```

Este JSON, y uno de la NASA son iguales, sólo tienes que aprender a leer su estructura, creando el tipo de objeto adecuado en cada caso y usando el método adecuado para sacar los datos.

Comment: Excelente explicación, me quedó clarisimo. Muchas gracias

Comment: @nerviosus me alegro de que te haya servido. Teniendo eso en cuenta no se te hará difícil saber cómo leer cualquier JSON en un futuro. Saludos.